# How do I get the While activity to run asynchronously in WF 4.0

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

I am building a workflow using WF 4.0. The workflow is built using the re-hosted workflow designer. I have written a custom activitiy named `FetchSqlDataReader` which inherits `AsyncCodeActivity`.

Multiple instances of `FetchSqlDataReader` are inside a `Parallel` activity.

Each of the instances executes a stored procedure and returns back a `SqlDataReader` as its output argument.

I want to iterate over each of the datareaders (in parallel) and execute a few more activities during each iteration.

I tried my hand at using the [AsyncNativeActivity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2011/06/09/wf4-they-have-asynccodeactivity-why-not-asyncnativeactivity.aspx). I created a custom activity which inherits the `AsyncNativeActivity`. In the `BeginExecute` part of my custom `WhileAsyncNativeActivity`, I do the following:

```
while(context.GetValue(Condition))
{
    context.ScheduleAction(Body);
}
```

`Condition` is of type `InArgument<Boolean>` which is set to `while(dataReader.Read())`. 
`context` is of type `NativeActivityContext` 
`Body` is of type `ActivityAction`. 
 
 The `Body` contains other activities which i dragged and dropped in the re-hosted workflow designer.

The idea here being as long as the data reader fetches values, execute the `Body` (all activities in the `WhileAsyncNativeActivity`)

I found that calling `context.ScheduleAction(Body)` only schedules (gasp :)) the Body and does not execute it.

In case my data reader has 1000 rows, i get a `OutOfMemory` exception after the `while` condition has iterated over the `context.ScheduleAction` call a few times.

How do i get the While activity to execute asynchonously? Is there a way I can call `ScheduleAction` and then have that action executed immediately (I guess not because the WF engine is in charge of activity execution). I have also tried calling `ScheduleActivity`, that too fails with an `OutOfMemory` exception

Until i find a way to get the `WhileAsyncNativeActivity` to work, I am passing the data reader to a custom activity derived from `AsyncCodeActivity` which will perform the iteration of the reader internally and then via reflection load a few assemblies and call their methods by passing them the data reader. This however would mean that the code written in those function is inside of assemblies and cannot be exposed as activities which the end-user could configure using the workflow designer.

Stuff I can't do:

1. Cannot use a dataset. The amount of data being retrieved is huge (over 500,000 rows of data) - per stored procedure and i am executing 6 of them in parallel.
2. Because i am relying on a `SqlDataReader` I can't convert my data into a `IEnumerable` collection, this means i cannot use `ParallelForEach`

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you create a List and then use ParallelFor in conjunction with async activities to process the list?

Comment: To create a List, I'd have to either, iterate over the DataReader or get all the data from the database at once. I can't do this as i am dealing with a large amount of data.

Comment: The problem is that you get the value, then schedule the action.  What you need to do is to defer reading the value until the action starts executing.

Comment: Yes. I would like to have the Body execute as soon as i schedule it, but I haven't found a way to do it.

Comment: Could you pass the DataReader to the activity and let the activity get the value from the DataReader?  That way, the data will not be read until the activity is actually executing.

Comment: Yes, I could do that but then how do I decide how many times the Body activity has to be executed? Presently, with the Async Native While Activity, I can eval the dataReader.Read() and then each of the child activities it holds in Body work on that instance of the data reader.

For each row in the DataReader I want to execute a bunch of activities. Each of those activities will take the datareader (which is a WF level variable) and act on its values. The only reason i had to create a Async While activity was because I have to execute multiple activities for each of the rows in the data reader.

Comment: Oh also, really appreciate you doing video sessions on workflow.tv :). Watched a bunch of them this weekend. Very helpful and informational.

Comment: Thanks - this is an interesting problem.  I'll think on this some more and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Thank you Ron. I'll see how the scheduling works if I call it inside of a 'Task'. Also, I need to measure how many times I can call 'Schedule' before I get a 'OutOfMemory' exception.

Comment: I think what we really need to do is to modify the ParallelFor behavior to provide a number of items to schedule before running them.  That way you could schedule a smaller number like 6 and then execute those first, as they complete, you schedule more and so on.  This throttling would prevent the problem you are seeing.

Comment: @RonJacobs I know this is an old post, but did you ever come with a work-around for this? I'm facing the same problem where I've got to recurse through a folder with millions of files and I wrote a library to do just that and it raises an event for each file found. In that event, I had hope to raise an ScheduleAction which I had hope would trigger the event in my workflow and allow me to perform whatever action was in my custom while loop but the ScheduleAction are not being triggered at all. Any suggestions/solutions? I've yet to come up with a solution!